# Strategies to prevent actions being carried out more than once in a loosely coupled system (using Azure Service Bus and Cloud Workers)

Tags: c#, azure, architecture, azureservicebus

I'm working on a system that sends multiple push notifications using Push Sharp.

My current design has two Service Bus Queues and two Cloud Worker Roles.

When the user wants to broadcast a notification, an ASP.Net Web App inserts a message into the Message-Queue, which gets read by Worker #1. Worker #1 determines the devices that are targeted by the notification (think 1000s). For each device, Worker #1 puts a message onto the Notification-Queue, This is done using Batching, so it's extremely very fast.

Worker #2 reads the messages on the Notification-Queue and sends the actual notification using Push Sharp.

If something goes wrong in Worker #2, the messages will be abandoned and eventually reprocessed, so I'm happy that this part is reliable and persistent.

My concern is Worker #1. If it fails whilst putting messages onto the Notification-Queue, it will abandon the message and try again. This could result in the same notification going onto the Notification-Queue several times, resulting in people getting annoyed when their device gets multiple alerts.

I'm considering using a database to track which notifications have been queued for which device, so Worker #1 won't queue a notification if it has already done so. This will obviously add a bottle neck to Worker #1. The ideal solution would be to wrap the writes to the Notification-Queue in a transaction, but Service Bus only allows 100 messages in a single transaction.

I've found lots of advice about making messages idempotent, but can't find a way to apply this to my situation.

I want to ensure that no matter what happens, a particular message is only sent to a particular device once. Any advice or design pattern suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sender can consistently generate the same message-id for the message, Service Bus has a feature for you: Duplicate detection.

It's enabled by the [RequiresDuplicateDetection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.requiresduplicatedetection.aspx) flag and further controlled by [DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.duplicatedetectionhistorytimewindow.aspx)

If we see the same MessageId again in the given time window, we throw away that second message.

Comment: Yes, I can generate a unique id (it would be <message_id>-<device_id>) so that looks ideal! Let me try it out.

Comment: Mind that bigger time window sizes will cost you throughput as the incoming message's id needs to be checked against the retained history.

Comment: I understand that. Ensuring indepotency always has a price :)